# How to return a double whole number with 2 zeros after the dot?

Tags: c#, return, double, digits

How can return a double whole number from double Method, such that it returns it with 2 numbers after the dot?

```
public static double ReturnDoubleWith2ZerosAfter(double wholeNumber)
{
   return wholeNumber;
}
```

```
Console.WriteLine(ReturnDoubleWith2ZerosAfter(4));

//Desired output should be like this:

4.00  // not 4
```

I have read many answers here. Nothing works for me. Most of them is by converting it to string e.g ("0:00"), (0:c),(0:##) etc. It should return double, not string.
Please help.

Comment: `.ToString("F2")`?

Comment: How you format a value isn't part of the value itself - at least not with `double`. There is no representation of 4.00 rather than 4. (There *is* in `decimal` though.) Asking for this is a bit like asking a method returning an `int` to return a hex int instead of a decimal int... the value is separate from how it's formatted.

Comment: Can you tell us _why_ you want this?

Comment: Trailing zeros after the decimal separator are not being stored as a part of the `double` type. I'm guessing it's because they are mathematically meaningless. They are being stored, however, in the `decimal` type.

Comment: To have desired output in console you need to convert it to string.

Comment: _" It should return double, not string."_ - What do you think `Console.WriteLine(...);` is doing? It's converting the value to a _string_. `double` is a means of storing a numeric value, two decimal places is _formatting_.

Comment: The bottom line is: it isn't possible in C# to apply formatting to a `double` variable. I imagine you'll find that most common programming languages are the same.

Comment: Thank you all. I got smarter. toda zohar.